# Does it take energy to destroy the surface of a liquid jet?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, energy, surface-tension

Imagine we have a collision of a liquid jet with an obstacle

Does it take time for the surface of the jet to be destroyed while collision?? Or it'll be destroyed immediately?

Comment: Why does it take energy to 'destroy' a surface?

Comment: As it needs energy to create the surface, it'll need energy to destroy it

Comment: No, it gains energy be reducing the surface energy. Adding more surface energy, or breaking the surface up, will take additional energy, because, well, you have more surface area.

Comment: So, What's my answer, does it take time or it'll be destroyed immediately?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking. What does "destroyed" mean? And a surface is an extended object, nothing happens to the whole thing "immediately". In any case, you can observe these processes in a laminar regime with any smoothly operating water facet (you may need to clear out the hard water deposits if it won't cooperate).

Comment: Do you mean like a jet hitting a large, solid wall? Or a jet hitting a thin cylinder? Or something else? Echoing dmckee, what do you mean by 'destroy' here?